# CreateGraphics for temporary messages

Tags: p5.js

So, I want to create a message that is shown on the screen for some time and then "get rid" of it.
The message might change and it's normally hidden.

I'm currently thinking of creating a message container with createGraphics, e.g.:

```
messagePoPup = createGraphics(200,120);
```

show it when needed, e.g.:

```
image(messagePoPup, 100, 100);
```

and hide it after a timeOut (either with setTimeOut or with millis), e.g.:

```
setTimeOut(messagePopUp.clear,1000);
```

So, what's the inverse of image(messagePoPup, 100, 100)?
I.e.: what should the hidePopUp function do? Would a messagePopUp.clear() do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a variable indicating if you should draw the popup, then inside `draw()` you either draw the popup or not depending on the variable value

```
let drawPopup = true;
let messagePoPup;

setup() {
  messagePoPup = createGraphics(200, 120);

  // Populate message popup with some text
  messagePopup.text("hello", 50, 50);

  // sets the drawPopup variable to false after 5 seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
    drawPopup = false;    
  }, 5000);
}

draw() {
  // clear the screen
  fill(255);

  // only draw the popup if the variable drawPopup is true
  if (drawPopup) {
     // draw the popup window
     image(messagePoPup, 100, 100);
  }
  // draw the rest of the page
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example, that uses the mouseClick() event as the trigger of the message. This is the same idea as @SembeiNorimaki's answer, so as I posted it later you may consider accepting that answer. I'm posting as an illustration of one way to do it:

```javascript
let renderer;
let mustDraw = false;
 
function setup() {
  // Set the canvas
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(255);
 
  // Create renderer and set text
  renderer = createGraphics(400, 300);
  renderer.background(255, 0);
  renderer.textSize(64);
  renderer.fill("black");
  renderer.text("My Text", 150, 50);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  
  if (mustDraw){
    image(renderer, 50, 50);  
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (!mustDraw) {
    mustDraw = true;
    setTimeout(function() {mustDraw = false}, 2000);  
  }
}
```